# USB Flash Icon Still appears After Removing Flash

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have Windows 7 and it has happened to me many times that when I remove my USB flash drive, the icon still appears in windows explorer and when I stick my USB drive again, it is not going to work until I reboot my PC!
How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to refresh Device Manager. For a short-term fix, try this:

1. Open Device Manager (type `devmgmt.msc` on the search box)
2. Click **Scan for hardware changes**

[image]